# Как скопировать value ключа из localstorage в значение textarea?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Как скопировать value ключа из localstorage в значение textarea? Чтобы потом использовать их при отправке формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="">
  <textarea>Пусто</textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

// Допустим, значение уже есть в localStorage
localStorage.setItem('myVal', 'Чем-то стало');
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Меняем значение в форме при загрузке страницы
  var myVal = localStorage.getItem('myVal');
  $('#form textarea').val(myVal);

  $('#form').on('submit', function(){
    // Меняем значение в форме при отправке формы
    var myVal = localStorage.getItem('myVal');
    $(this).find('textarea').val(myVal);
  });
});
```

[Пример](https://codepen.io/jsfun/pen/paBXbO)

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea id="textArea1"></textarea>

var value1 = localStorage.getItem("name1");
document.getElementById("textArea1").value = value1;
```

Документация по `localStorage`.

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
2. https://metanit.com/web/javascript/12.2.php